# can't figure out correct logic of redirecting rules in .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting, rule

I have a URL that has a query string like so:

```
www.blablabla.com/index.php?page=details&p_name=van-der-var&p_country=holland
```

I would like to rewrite the URL to look like this:

```
www.blablabla.com/van-der-var-holland.html
```

I could do something like this:

```
www.blablabla.com/van_der_var-holland.html
```

but I need to use the same symbol in the name and other parameters together. Is it possible?

My current `.htaccess` file looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^p-([A-Za-z0-9_]+)-([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\.html$ index\.php?main_page=person&p_name=$1&p_country=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a way to solve it with using same separator between the variables and words in variables, that is considering that your country names could be 2 or more words. If country is always one word, @faa's solution would do what you need. Otherwise, I would suggest the following:

**van_der_var-holland.html**

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_]+).html$ index.php?page=details&p_name=$1&p_country=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

**van-der-var_holland.html**

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)_([a-zA-Z0-9-]+).html$ index.php?page=details&p_name=$1&p_country=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

**van-der-var/holland.html**

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).html$ index.php?page=details&p_name=$1&p_country=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

or something similar with any other separator, like a comma for instance.

Comment: +1 For pointing out the problems with the solution the OP is asking for.